# stop link from navigating if js/ajax navigation function exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

so here is my link

```
    <a href="www.site.com/get_myinfo" onclick="check_navigation_exist('info');" >
 my info </a>
```

this is what i want

```
        function check_navigation_exist(wher_togo){

            if(typeof(navigator) != 'undefined'
               && 
            $.isFunction(navigator))
            {
                navigator(wher_togo);
                    return false ;
            }
            else
            return ;


        }




  function navigator(where)
    {
        $('#profile_main').html('<img src="'+image_url+'loader.gif" />');
        $.post(base_url+'profile/'+where , function(data){
            $('#profile_main').html(data);
            if(where != 'get_edit')
            odd();
        })  
    }

    function odd(color){
         color = typeof(color) == 'undefined' ? '#DCEABB' : color ;
         $('tr:odd').css('background-color' , color  );
    }
```

but it doesn't stop link from navigating

Comment: Well.... Use your eyes. It's telling you exactly what the error is. Where is it you think you're defining `e`?

Comment: The solution to your problem is to stop using inline `onclick` attributes, use data attributes to store additional data in your markup, and bind to your events externally with jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting that error because `e` in not in your parameter list. Normally you will be able to use `e.preventDefault()` but since you're calling a function in your `onclick` instead of assigning a function you will need another method as you don't have access to the event.

Try returning `false` to prevent the default action, and return the result of the function call in your `onclick` event.

```
<a href="www.site.com/get_myinfo" onclick="return check_navigation_exist('info');">my info </a>
```

JS

```
function check_navigation_exist(wher_togo){

    if (typeof(navigator) != 'undefined' && 
        $.isFunction(navigator))
    {
        navigator(wher_togo);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks i know it should work , but it doesn't .. i should have mentioned that , `navigator` is a ajax function (it sends a ajax request) ...  maybe it doesn't stop default link behavior becuz  `check_navigation_exist` waits for `navigator` function to be done and then it runs `return false` ?

Comment: It shouldn't wait for `navigator` to complete as the AJAX request will be started asynchronously. And the link shouldn't be followed until its `onclick` function has been called. Are there any errors on your page maybe? Posting `navigator`'s code may be useful, as well as any JS errors if they exist.

Comment: i've added the rest of code , i didn't want to do this but i think i have to remove href attribute from  `a` tag and put the link in `rel` attr and read it from there in the function ,  or send it as argument to the function and do the all the navigation from function

Comment: @max you would be better off putting it in some custom `data-` attribute rather than `rel` otherwise it will contain invalid data. Use something like `data-href` which is a (HTML5) custom attribute.